# AI Pathfinding using 2D polygons instead of waypoints - Is there a recommended algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I'm trying to use path finding on a series of convex polygons, rather than waypoints. To even further complicate this, the polygons are made by the users, and may have inconsistent vertices. For example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgzX3.png]

We know the object is X wide by Y deep, and that the polygons have vertices at certain locations. Is there a specific algorithm to find the fastest way to the goal while keeping the entire object in the polygons (If I understand correctly, A* only works on waypoints)? How do you handle the vertices not being the same object but being at the same location?

EDIT: The polygons are convex; It's 2 separate polygons with the edges on the line.
Also, how do you implement * pathfinding, as a node based system wouldn't work in a 'infinite' resolution polygon?

Comment: That polygon is not convex (there are vertex-to-vertex lines that exit the polygon)

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained better; Thaw was 2 separate polygons.

Comment: We get that there are two polygons. But neither of them is convex.

Comment: @DonReba Never mind, I see what you mean. If you drew a line between vertices, some would self intersect. This would be a convex representation, right? http://i.imgur.com/e2xA040.png

Comment: @user2841239 - if you try to go from the sharp corner (in your updated image) to the goal, you will see that "best path always passes through mid of each convex polygon" is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, all shortest-path segments will have, as end-points, either polygon vertices or the start and goal points. If you build a graph that includes all those segments (from the start to each "visible" polygon vertex, from the goal to each "visible" polygon vertex, from the start to the goal, and from each polygon vertex to each other polygon vertex) and run A* on that, you have your optimal path. The cost of building the graph for A* is:

- For each vertex, a visibility-test to find visible vertices: the simple algorithm (for each pair of vertices, see if the segment from one to another lies inside the polygon) is O(n^3). Building convex polygons and processing them independently, or using a smarter "radial sweep" algorithm can greatly lower this, but I suspect it is still around O(n^2).
- For each query (from a start-point to a goal-point), O(n) for the visibility-test to find all vertices that it can see.

If you are only going to apply A* once, then the price of building the fixed part of the A* graph for a single traversal may be somewhat steep. An alternative is to build the graph incrementally as you use it:

[image: illustrated example]

Java code implementing the above approach can be found [here](https://github.com/e-ucm/ead/blob/master/engine/core/src/main/java/es/eucm/ead/engine/paths/PathFinder.java).

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot more sense. I'm still a little confused - what if an optimal route is not vertex to vertex - like the picture I posted originally. It would not be poly center to center, but also edge to edge.

Comment: It's fairly easy to prove that except for the starting point and the destination all direction changes of the optimal route happen turning around concave vertices: if a path has a corner anywhere else, a shorter path closer to the obstacle exist.

Comment: Before executing the A*, you need to check if it's valid or not to include the direct start-to-goal edge in the graph, right? And that seems expensive since you need to check every single polygon edge to see if anyone intersects it.

Answer (score 2):

The polygons in your drawing are not convex. For convex polygons, you can place a way point in the middle of each each edge and then apply A*. And, of course, you need to fix inconsistent vertices.

Comment: That does not guarantee an optimal path. Imagine a big square. Take out a smaller square in the middle (forming a square donut). Build convex polygons (4 trapezes). Place points in middle of each. Optimal path from one side to another should hug the inner empty square, but using your algorithm, it does not => not optimal.

Comment: @tucuxi, good call. Placing the nodes at the vertices and connecting all nodes inside each convex polygon should do the trick, then. Right?

Comment: Yes, but you also need to add start and goal, and connect nodes by visibility, and not polygon adjacency. I can clarify my answer, but this one is certainly non-optimal

Comment: Every vertex in a convex polygon is visible from any other. The polygons are cliques in the way point graph.